# Why there is no main method in applet?

Tags: java

Where from the execution starts in an applet?
Is it true that since an applet program is not a standalone application so it does not have a main method?

Comment: Tried reading a tutorial? Besides: applets are dead technology.

Comment: Applets are unsafe and should be regarded as unusable.  Oracle is deprecating both the Applet and JApplet libraries in Java 9

Answer (score 0):

Applets run in a browser or some kind of applet runner. they are not standalone applications and were designed so that they could be executed as a part of a web page.
Also, as @GhostCat mentioned, it is pretty much a dead technology.

Comment: Can you tell me the technology currently being used?